# vb.net System.IFormatProvider runtime error

Tags: vb.net

I have this function in vb.net:

```
Function GetFirstDayOfMonth(ByVal dtDate As DateTime) As DateTime
        Dim dtFrom As DateTime = dtDate
        dtFrom = dtFrom.AddDays(-(dtFrom.Day - 1))
        Return dtFrom
End Function
```

I am then calling it here:

GetFirstDayOfMonth(reader3.GetString(3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))

I have checked the value of `reader3.GetString(3)` using a `MsgBox` and it equals

```
2015-02-23
```

But i am getting a runtime error saying:

```
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IFormatProvider'.
```

Comment: You're sending a string value into a function that requires a DateTime. Turning `option strict` on should turn this into a compile time error.

Comment: You're passing in a string to the function which specifies that a DateTime object is provided.

Comment: Using DataTableReader.GetDateTime() instead.  If that fails then fix the huge mistake, never ever stores dates as strings in a dbase.

Comment: how can i make that string DateTime instead?

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a string value into a function that requires a DateTime.

```
Dim tmp as DateTime

' Don't use the string format here. If it's already 
' a string - GetString - then it doesn't need a date format
' I recommend listening to @Hans Passant and @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå
' If your data is already a date, use the date functions to
' keep it as a date
Dim tmpStr As String = reader3.GetString(3)   

If DateTime.TryParse(tmpStr, tmp) Then
    GetFirstDayOfMonth(tmp)
End If
```

To keep it as a date without ever casting or formatting it (assuming it's a date object in the database)

```
Dim firstDay As DateTime = GetFirstDayOfMonth(reader3.GetDateTime(3))
```

Additionally, turning option strict on should turn this into a compile time error (much more useful).

Comment: in the tmpStr variable im still seeing the runtime error

Comment: in the database, the column is datetime but i am selecting it using date(timestamp) as call_date